# Ajax selecting a portion of the DOM

Tags: jquery, ajax

I'm trying to load just a portion of the resulting html file into a particular div. This one supposedly should work.  Can't get anything to work.  Any help appreciated.

```
    $.ajax({
        url: href,
          dataType: "html",
        success: function(data) {
            $(loaddiv).html($(data).find(selectdiv));
        }
    });
```

EDIT:

I uploaded the complete example code to http://jsfiddle.net/BHruska/x7mzR/.

Comment: Can't do that much without the rest of the code. Could you set up a test case @ [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) including html and the rest of the js?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$(loaddiv).load(href + ' ' + selectdiv);
```

This should only load the dom based upon the selector. Here is a better example from the jquery load help page.

```
$('#result').load('ajax/test.html #container');
```

The above snippet loads the html at 'ajax/test.html' inside the element with the id '#container' into the '#result' element.

Hope this helps.

Bob

Comment: A caveat when doing this: though when a *complete* response is loaded into the existing DOM with ".load()" jQuery runs embedded `<script>` blocks, it does **not** do so when you pluck out part of the response as this answer suggests.  I'm not saying this is wrong; quite the opposite. It's just a weirdness of jQuery that sometimes causes problems.

Comment: Yes, I've used .load.  What I'm trying to do is to get whats INSIDE the DIV, not the div itself.  Without this you end up with two copies of the same DIV in the resulting HTML file.  I've monkeyed with a million selectors trying to get what's inside the div only, but I can't get anything that works.

Comment: @Bth to get a jQuery collection with everyhing inside a DIV, try selecting the normally and then use the [.contents()](http://api.jquery.com/contents) method - it captures not only the child *elements* but also the `textNode` children.

Answer (score 0):

You need to put data in some DOM element and then find in it. The data would not be in DOM and hence .find will not work.

Comment: I uploaded the code to http://jsfiddle.net/BHruska/x7mzR/

It needs to be saved to TestDivLoad.htm.

Comment: $("#someTempdiv").html($(data));
$(loaddiv).html($("#someTempdiv #"+ selecdiv).html()); $("#someTempdiv").html("");

Answer (score 0):

There is a problem with this line:

```
$(loaddiv).html( $(data).find(selectdiv) );
```

The `.html()` method expects an HTML string input, but `$(data).find(selectDiv)` emits a collection of DOM elements.[1]

The `.append()` method, however, is probably what you were looking for, as it accepts element collection for input. So, try this:

```
$(loaddiv)
    .empty()
    .append( $(data).find(selectdiv) );
```

.

[1] Assuming that `selectDiv` is a selector string, of course.